# New row should visible at top of the DataGrid in WPF once vertical scroll bar starts visible

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF. I am working on a WPF application with **MVVM **pattern. I have used Datagrid and a new row should be entered into the top of the data grid after the visibility of the vertical scrollbar.
The content reached the maximum height of Datagrid and the vertical scrollbar is also start showing but when I added new data on top of the data grid the content of Datagrid is not moving and I am not able to see the top and newly inserted row on Datagrid. The vertical scrollbar moves down instead of moving up.

Current scenario:
[Currently, the scrollbar is down and new data is added at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUKa9.png)

Desired Scenario:
[Expected, the new row should be at top along with vertical scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckbz6.png)

I have used the below code in

```
 if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    _dataModel.SurveyUIValues.Insert(0, surveyUI);
                });
            }
```

Where SurveyUIValues is a collection. As you can see I have used the Insert method and the given index is 0 to insert data at the top of the Datagrid.

```
public ObservableCollection<SurveyUI> SurveyUIValues { get; set; }
```

and SurveyUI is a model.
I have used:
MVVM.toolkit library.

My XAML code it looks like this:

```
<DataGrid 
            x:Name="dgSurvey"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="25*"
                    Binding="{Binding CurrentDateTime}"
                    Header="Time/Date" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="10*"
                    Binding="{Binding Depth}"
                    Header="Depth" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="20*"
                    Binding="{Binding Measurement}"
                    Header="Measurement" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="25*"
                    Binding="{Binding Value}"
                    Header="Value" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="20*"
                    Binding="{Binding DecodedType}"
                    Header="Decoded Type" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

There is a Viewmodel binded through Datacontext with the view.

Note: New rows are automatically/dynamically adding using thread.

Can someone help me or what I am missing.

Comment: could you add a picture showing what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Liero: I have added sample images. Current Vs Expected. I hope it will be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to call `dgSurvey.ScrollIntoView(insertedRecord);`

Your `ObservableCollection<SurveyUI> SurveyUIValues` notifies you, when you add new item, so take advantage of that.

In CodeBehind of a UserControl / Page / Window that contains the DataGrid, you can call scroll when you are notified about the change in the collection:

```cs
void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _dataModel.SurveyUIValues.CollectionChanged += SurveyUIValues_CollectionChanged;
}
void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _dataModel.SurveyUIValues.CollectionChanged -= SurveyUIValues_CollectionChanged;
}

void SurveyUIValues_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
   {
      dgSurvey.ScrollIntoView(e.NewItems[0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Will it not violence of MVVM architecture rule? By the way, let me try it out. Thank you !

Comment: Writing pure presentation logic in code behind is not violation of MVVM. The VM notifies you view about changes and view reacts to the change - beautiful. MVVM doesn't specify, that the reaction must be implemented using Binding

Comment: Thank you so much Liero. I applied these solutions and now work perfectly as I wanted. Due to my low reputation, I am unable to upvote the solution. sorry for that. You are just awesome.